# how to get the event that switch tab menu on iphone

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, uitabbarcontroller

I'm trying to figure out how to catch the event that controls the switch tabs on the
`UITabBarController`. How could I accomplish this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you are using storyboard, do this

in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

```
UITabBarController *tabBar = (UITabBarController *)self.window.rootViewController;
[tabBar setDelegate:self];
```

Also in AppDelegate, keep `<UITabBarControllerDelegate>`

And then

```
-(void) tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
   //Write your code here
}
```

Answer (score 37):

Implement `UITabBarControllerDelegate` e.g. in your app delegate's `applicationDidFinishLaunching`

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application
{
    tabBarController.delegate = self;
    [window addSubview:tabBarController.view];
}
```

Then implement either:

```
- (BOOL)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController shouldSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController;

- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController;
```

The first method is called before the view switch and gives you a chance to 'veto' the view switch by returning `NO`

The second method is called after the view switch has taken place

Answer (score 6):

Better late than never. In case of swift 4 you can do it in the following way.

```
tabBarViewController.delegate = self
```

And implement `UITabBarDelegate` in your class.
You will get the callback in

```
override func tabBar(_ tabBar: UITabBar, didSelect item: UITabBarItem) {
  //Stuff to do
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Have a look at the following method in UITabBarControllerDelegate:

```
- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
```

> Tells the delegate that the user
>   selected an item in the tab bar.

Answer (score 1):

Is `UITabBarControllerDelegate` what you're looking for, particularly -`tabBarController:didSelectViewController:`?