# how to reload tableview upon return to tableviewcontroller

Tags: ios, uitableview, parse-platform

In my app, there are tabs. I have one tableviewcontroller that contains messages and I have implemented pull to refresh so that works fine. However, if the user goes from the message tab to another tab and then back to the message tab, the uitableview doesn't reload and the user has to pull to refresh. I have thought of putting [self.tableview reloadData] or [self loadObjects] (i am using Parse) in viewDidLoad/viewWilAppear, but that doesn't seem to work...it's because they are only called when the view controller is initially visited right? So I'm wondering as to where I should put that code so that the table view can be reloaded every time the view controller is revisited?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`viewWillAppear` and `viewDidAppear` are both called every time the view controller appears. If you call `reloadData` in one of those methods then it will refresh the table view.

I think your problem is you aren't updating your data source. You will need to make another call to Parse otherwise your table view will just reload with the same data.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that this behavior is desirable. I suggest you tu wait for a reasonable timeout before updating data, or your user will experience lags and high network usage.
However to do that, you should set a delegate that fires when the corresponding view is loaded (take a look here [how to get the event that switch tab menu on iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2041982/how-to-get-the-event-that-switch-tab-menu-on-iphone) ) and then call

> [yourTableView reloadData]

inside didSelectViewController