# On click on already selected TabBarItem's View, Restart/Reopen ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbaritem

I have a TabBarController. It's going through pages when I click on TabBarItems, however if I try to click on the TabBarItem that is already selected, it doesn't do anything, and I couldn't find a way to get the click event either.

When I click on the selected TabBarItem, I want to restart/reopen the ViewController (and if I have a tableview, go to the top) as if it's getting navigated from another TabBarItem's page.

Is there a way to get click event on already selected/open TabBarItem and reopen/restart the UIView?

Comment: are you using UITabBarController or UITabBar?

Comment: UITabBarController

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2041982/how-to-get-the-event-that-switch-tab-menu-on-iphone

Comment: you will get the tab selection action by this way as shown in above link..